# PHP use of what appears to be an operator "=>"

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Take this snippet of code for instance:

```
$files[] = array('name' => $d, 'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i]);
```

What is the specific definition, name and usage of what only appears to be the operator `=>`

Answer (score 0):

It's the separator for key-value pairs in arrays.  See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` is an array assignment operator.  When you're creating an array with both keys and values, the `=>` maps the key to a value.

For instance:

```
$example = array("Person" => "SomeKittens");
$example["Person"]  === "SomeKittens"; //true
isset($example[0]);//false.  The 0 index was never set.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an assignment operator used in array definitions.

```
$someVar=array('key1' => 3, 'key2' => 6);
```

The output is an array with an element called 'key1' and the value of 3 and a second one called 'key2' with a value of 6.